# How do I remove a "&" symbol from a URL using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, url

how to remove a `&` Symbol from a url address use php regular?
for example:`http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=php`
left the `&` and get :`http://www.google.com/search?hl=enq=php`
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=php';
$url = str_replace('&', '', $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really understand the question.  It sounds like you just want to remove `&` characters.  That can be easily done:

```
$url = str_replace('&', '', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it easily enough with str_replace.  Why you would want to do this, however, is another matter entirely.

Are you trying to insert a URL into a page with PHP and getting validation errors due to the & symbol?  In that case urlencode() might be what you really need.

Comment: This isn't an answer, questions about the question are usually best framed as comments.